# pkttyagent:3798 while runinng the nginx service

Tags: centos, centos-7

While running the nginx service this error occured for my localhost and nginx service automatically stopped and other services also stopped

Comment: ... what error?

Comment: "WARNING **: 16:02:03.979: Unable to register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
Error registering authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2)
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for detail  " THIS ERROR IS OCCURED

Comment: @grawity  any idea.......?